# Android XML escape "@" Symbol

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How do you use the `@` as text in an Android XML file, as it has special meaning? I have a `TextView` which will simply hold the text `@`

I tried:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/at_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/account_name"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:text="@" />
```

That of course did not work with the error

> error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'text' with value '@').

So I tried pointing it to an entry in `strings.xml` like this:
`<string name="at">@</string>` and that shows the error:

> error: Error: No resource type specified (at 'at' with value '@').

So how do I escape `@` as the text for a TextView?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use this way ..............

```
 <string name="at">\@</string>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
android:text="\@"
              ^
```

**instead of**

```
android:text="@"
```