# How to write @ as string in Java

Tags: java, android, string, textview

How do I write @ as an string in java.
When I write "@" it indicate as missing resource type
This is my TextView

```
<TextView 
android:height="wrap_content";
android:width="wrap_content";
android:text="@";
/>
```

Comment: You could try "\@"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11169051/5868421

Answer (score 3):

The @ symbol is used for resources reference inside xml files. 
The advisable way to do this is define the same inside values/string resources as

```sh
<string name="at_sign">"@"</string>
...
```

Then use it

```sh
...
<TextView 
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/at_sign"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using @ you could use \u0040 (the unicode character). An other solution: define a string resource and use this in your `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:text="\@"
```

**OR**

Using backslash :

```
<string name="at">\@</string>
```

**OR**

Using quote :

```
<string name="at">"@"</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a simple addition of backslash before such special character. It's not only for @ but for single quote, double quotes, colon etc.

Hope this helps. Put the below code and see if it helps.

```
<TextView 
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"
android:text="\@"/>
```